# increase database size on ipad

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Every time I try to sign into yahoo mail on my ipad, a pop-up asks whether I want to increase database size to 10MB. but whether I select Increase or Cancel, it just freezes (spinning wheel) and won't let me get to my email. Please help!! The pop-up returns every time. I'd be happy to increase but it won't let me!

Comment: You are trying to log into Yahoo via Safari, correct?

Answer (score 2):

This warning is there to prevent people from over filling their devices with local data and also to keep developers in check from not over stuffing the content that gets stored locally.

I don't think there is a way to white list one site to have increased space. I would clear thing by first quitting Safari using multitasking controls, and then go to the settings app -> Safari -> Advanced -> Website Data and clear all the data.

That would allow it to start cleanly. You also might want to be sure your device itself wasn't totally full by checking Usage under general in the settings app.